# How To Start a Dedicated Black Ops 1 Server on PC

Tags: hosting, call-of-duty-black-ops

How do I start a dedicated server that shows in the server browsers on the legal version of BO1 on PC?

I know about GameServers being the official way to run a dedicated server, but their order page does not have Black Ops 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out GTXGaming. I've used them for multiple games and never had a problem with them. I hosted a World at War server back in the day but never tried Black Ops 1. Dont, see why it would be a problem. Also if you have money to dispose of, try renting a dedicated server and you can put anything you want on it.

P.S. When I say dedicated server I mean renting a non-game server and putting a game on it. Not a premade one.